# Why does my Scikit-Learn Linear Regression model only work for certain random states?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I am trying to run a machine learning linear regression model to predict the review score of different whiskies, using this data set:  https://whiskyanalysis.com/index.php/database/

Where I use the train/test split method I can specify a random state. If I specify certain ramdon states (e.g. random_state = 3) the model behaves as intented and the predictions are within expected ranges (~ 8.0). For certain other random_state numbers (e.g. random_state = 2) the model fails and makes several predictions that are far from the expected values (many powers of 10 wrong!)

I am at a loss to explain this behaviour.

I am running sckit-learn v20.0 in Anaconda Navigator 1.9.2, Python 3.6.5.

Thanks in advance for any help - here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('whisky_analysis.csv')
df.head()

#get rid of the spaces!
df.rename(columns={'Meta Critic':'Score','Super Cluster':'Super_Cluster'}, inplace=True)

# replace special character $ with £ 
df.Cost = df.Cost.str.replace('$','£')

df.shape

df.isna().sum()

# Drop the 'Whisky', 'STDEV' and # columns
# Drop 'Cluster' and 'Super_Cluster' due to large numbers of NaN  
df = df.drop(['Whisky', 'STDEV', '#', 'Super_Cluster', 'Cluster'], axis=1)

# drop any remaining rows with NaNs
df = df.dropna()

#Use one hot encoding to vectorise the categorical variables - we will use pandas' get_dummies 
df1 = pd.get_dummies(df, columns = ['Cost', 'Type', 'Class','Country'])

# get target and feature vector/matrix
y = df1.pop('Score')
y.shape
X = df1
X.shape

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 2)

from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
reg = LinearRegression().fit(X_train, y_train)
preds = reg.predict(X_test)

preds

# evaluating performance
from sklearn.metrics import mean_absolute_error
mean_absolute_error(y_test, preds)

from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
r2_score(y_test, preds)
```

Comment: From the docs, "random_state is the seed used by the random number generator". So, because the random number generator used to decide which data goes into the train and test sets, you are basically feeding it slightly different datasets. It doesn't look like you're doing any scoring on your training set, but I'd be willing to bet that due to the data selected, you are overfitting to the train set and not generalizing well to the test set.  [cross validation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html) can help prevent this.

Comment: @G.Anderson Hi, thanks for commenting. I will try cross validation as you suggest. What leads you to suspect over-fitting is a problem?

Comment: I suppose I overstated the likelihood of overfitting. Anytime I see the same data giving different prediction scores without seeing training scores, that's my first go-to assumption. It could really be anything, though, it could be outliers or odd data patterns. I would look into crossvalidating and trying different regularization on your model to rule some of the possibilities

Comment: @G.Anderson Good ideas, thank you.